# Tell if point belongs to ray in 3D space

Tags: c++, c++11, geometry, computational-geometry

I have this problem: verify if point belongs to ray in 3D. After some math research, I've coded the solution, but it seems that it just doesn't work.
[image]
That's the illustration. **P** is the point. **E** - the end-point of ray. **V** - directional vector of the ray.

```
double x, y, z, e1, e2, e3, v1, v2, v3, d, xVectorFromEToP, 
dirVectorMagnitude,  vectorEPMagnitude, yVectorFromEToP, zVectorFromEToP, 
cpX, cpY, cpZ;
cin >> x >> y >> z >> e1 >> e2 >> e3 >> v1 >> v2 >> v3;

// HERE I'M FORMING THE EP vector - from point P to end-point E

xVectorFromEToP = x - e1;
yVectorFromEToP = y - e2;
zVectorFromEToP = z - e3; 

//HERE I'M CALCULATING CROSS-PRODUCT of THE VECTORS: EP and V

cpX = ((v2 * zVectorFromEToP) - (v3 * yVectorFromEToP));
cpY = ((v1 * zVectorFromEToP) - (v3 * xVectorFromEToP)) * -1;
cpZ = ((v1 * yVectorFromEToP) - (v2 * xVectorFromEToP)); 

// HERE I'M CALCULATING MAGNITUDES OF THOSE VECTORS AND DEBUGGING IN COUT

vectorsEpVMagnitude = sqrt(pow(cpX, 2) + pow(cpY, 2) + pow(cpZ, 2));
dirVectorMagnitude = sqrt(pow(v1, 2) + pow(v2, 2) + pow(v3, 2));

cout << "EP: " << vectorsEpVMagnitude << endl;
cout << "dir: " << dirVectorMagnitude << endl;

// final formula for calculating distance

d = vectorsEpVMagnitude / dirVectorMagnitude;

// precision is 1e-8: 1 means belong, otherwise - 0;

if (d < 1e-8) {
    cout << "distance: " << d << endl;
    cout << 1;
} else {
    cout << "distance: " << d << endl;
    cout << 0;
}
```

I have sample inputs: 1) P(2.0 1.0 0.0), E(2.0 1.0 1.0), V(0.0 0.0 1.0) should be 0;

2) P(2.0 1.0 0.0), E(2.0 1.0 1.0), V(0.0 0.0 -1.0) should be 1!

However both of them have distance equal to 0, while as stated they should have different distance. I would appreciate any help, clarification, etc.

Comment: so as i understand your description you want to tell if the Point P is on the line that is formed by the Point E and the vector V is that correct?
Your result is always 0 because the E you choose is on the line. So The cross product you calculate is always zero because the vecors have the same direction

Comment: I'd suggest you learn what each variable means. Then do the calculations on paper and cross check with the values from the algorithm.

Comment: @AmirKrasnic I calculate the distance: if its 0, then point is on the ray (line from point E to eternity in the direction of the vector V). I actually did it on paper firstly, but I guess I'm just missing the concept. Anyway..

Comment: your second example should also be 0 because it is completely the same as the first only the vector has the opposite direction. but the point still lies on the ray so the distance is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code calculates distance to **infinite line** (it looks fine), so in the both cases point lies on the line (essentially it is the same line).

Edit: Note that point lies on the ray in the second case, not in the first case, as Amir Krasnic noticed in comments.

To check whether projection of P lies on the ray, calculate scalar (dot) product of **EP** and **V** and look at its sign.

If it is positive, then projection of P lies on the ray, and `d = vectorsEpVMagnitude / dirVectorMagnitude;`  is valid result

If negative - point lies back from the ray (behind?), in this case just calculate **EP** length

Comment: much thx, very helpful, clarified it a bit for me! Unfortunately, only 4/10 test cases passed good. [This](https://pastebin.com/NFCMQQ1j) is mine modified version based on your advice about dot product.

Comment: Seems you output 0 only when dot is negative, but nothing for case `d >= 1e-8`

Comment: Omg, I really overlooked that. Unfortunately, hah, it's 9/10 now. Sorry for bothering you actually did help a lot, but one case is failing and I can't even figure what is the edge case here.. Oh, is `dotProductEpV >= 0` actually right? Cause somehow I've submitted `dotProductEpV > 0` instead.

Comment: `dotProductEpV=0` denotes that P lies in the plane, containing point P and perpendicular to V. How to consider that case - `on ray` or `off ray` -  depends on your needs. Seems that `dotProductEpV > 0` is more suitable for you